Import auth to client code in next js with auth.js
I have an auth.js file that authenticates users by checking a PostgreSQL database:

const providers = [
    Credentials({
        credentials: {
            email: {},
            password: {},
        },
        authorize: async (credentials) => {
            const res = await query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=$1', [credentials.email]);
            if (res.rows.length > 0) {
                const user = res.rows[0];
                const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(credentials.password, user.password);
                if (passwordsMatch) return user;
            }
            return null;
        },
    }),
];

export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
    providers,
});

But I cannot use this authentication in middleware or in other client components.
If I use it in middleware, I get an error: The edge runtime does not support Node.js 'crypto' module after adding middleware.js.
If I use it in client components, I get this error:
./node_modules/pg-connection-string/index.js:76:1
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
How can I fix this?
